# Structure of nested queries in SQL that are based on frequencies

Tags: sql

Noob question.
Trying to put together a nested query and having some issues.

So I have one table, it contains information on store transactions.
I am trying to pull the store name and value for those stores where there are many occurences.

So something like this made sense to me. I realize that some nested query is needed whereby I need to add something to the where section whereby I pick only those stores that meet the activity condition.

```
SELECT store, value
FROM table
WHERE group = 'C'
AND (
    SELECT store, 
      count(*) as total_activity
    FROM table
    WHERE group = 'C'
    GROUP BY store
    ) > 1000
```

The issue is that I'm not sure how to structure the query.

Expected output would be

```
store   value
101      3442
101      3434 
101      3433 
102
102
102
..
```

The table has a store column, so the count just gets a count of their frequency. I just want the rows where the store occurs frequently

Comment: can you give example of data and expected result? I think I can help write query to get expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT store, value
FROM (
SELECT store, value, 
  count(*) as total_activity
FROM table
WHERE group = 'C', total_activity > 1000
GROUP BY store )
```